# IE auth cookie is not passing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, cookies

I am using an asp.net M V C application.when i log in in IE,First time log in is possible.From the next log in request the authentication token is not passed in the request header.

At first time log in i got the response code as 200 OK .Then during the next log in i get response status code as 304 Not modified and my token is not passing in request header.What is the actual issue with IE?

Here the i am using form authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".AUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
```

In debugging mode login and auth token are passing.But when i host it these issues are comming

Comment: 301 <> Not Modified, 304 = Not Modified, and 301 = moved permanently. Please first clarify which exact response code you get since they can be absolutely different cases. Also you'd better explain or leave some code of your login form and login progress for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: my bad its 304 Not Modified.First time this login is possible

Comment: Then that means your login action result has been cached. This is not usual since usually login request are POSTs and should not be cached by default. Can you explain your detailed login progress (better with some minimum code)? Is it through a regular form post, or an ajax form post, or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have analysed the ajax request in IE ,304 result is comming because its loading from cache.So during the second time login the request is not hitted in server.The data required is loaded from cache.So i have found a solution that before calling the ajax request you have to add

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Now my application works fine and authentication is working properly